# What is the proper way to insert a subsection into a section / end a subsection within a section?

Tags: style, academic-writing, research, chapters

Not sure if this belongs here, or math.stackexchange but what's the proper way to do a special case subsection in a section? This is mostly in a proof/logical statement context

i.e.   To show ...
\begin{subsection}{If A was true}
...
\end{subsection}
continuing the proof ...

\begin{subsection}{If B was true}
\end{subsection}
...
In a real writeup I'm not sure about titling a section end of previous section or returning to the main case...

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd say TeX.SE is your best bet, this looks like a LaTeX-specific problem.

Comment: @F1Krazy  Okay just to clarify I also don't know how I want it to appear even if I was doing it in word or just writing it by hand.  

What is the proper way to insert a subsection into a section so to speak?

Comment: @F1Krazy: The OP may want to correct me, but to me, the question reads as if TeX had been used solely to illustrate where the subsection ends, whereas the question is actually how to represent/indicate that end of a subsection *beyond* TeX (in particular, in the final layouted document).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper  yes I actually didn't even know that began a section until you mentioned it I had previously just been using \section  
I don't quite like that style as there isn't anything to indicate the section has ended unless you start a new section with a new section title

Comment: If this is a question about how to _code_ the LaTeX, then migrate this to TeX.SE.  If this is a question about the visual aspect of the resulting formatting, then refer to the journal's guidelines and standards.